# Acces file from other project where the source is

Tags: java

I have a project(project source) with .txt file which I want to access from other project (project caller).  caller has dependecy over source. So caller should see source as .jar. Well, the question, I have to access to this .jar to obtenin the .txt file but I cannot. I have tried thinks like:
getClass().getResourceAsStream("classpath:/cc.txt"); with InsputStream
and getClass().getResource("cc.txt"); with URL object
but I always got a null. All forums I ve read speaks about this way to access.
How do I suposse to access to a .jar file to get the .txt file?
thanks all!!

Comment: A text file is not supposed to be in a JAR I think...

Comment: Looks like closest duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963410/trying-to-get-a-properties-file-from-a-jar-file-in-another-jar-file

Comment: @colditz: If u have got ur answer please tick mark it....

Answer (score 0):

Extract the Contents of ZIP/JAR Files Programmatically. Suppose jarFile is the jar/zip file to be extracted. destDir is the path where it will be extracted:

```
java.util.jar.JarFile jar = new java.util.jar.JarFile(jarFile);
java.util.Enumeration enum = jar.entries();
while (enum.hasMoreElements()) 
{
    java.util.jar.JarEntry file = (java.util.jar.JarEntry) enum.nextElement();
    java.io.File f = new java.io.File(destDir + java.io.File.separator + file.getName());
    if (file.isDirectory())  // if its a directory, create it
    {
        f.mkdir();
        continue;
    }
    java.io.InputStream is = jar.getInputStream(file); // get the input stream
    java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(f);
    while (is.available() > 0)  // write contents of 'is' to 'fos'
    {  
       fos.write(is.read());
    }
    fos.close();
    is.close();
}
```

[the same question can be found here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529611/how-to-write-a-java-program-which-can-extract-a-jar-file-and-store-its-data-in-s)

Comment: But, If I want to use getResource() or getResourceAsStream() from the getClass is not possible?